# Проблема с Postgresql в Hibernate

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

Мне понадобилось переконфигурировать Hibernate с Mysql на Postgresql. При запуске получаю исключение:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Error accessing index information: organizations_departments
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:106)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.convertSQLException(InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.java:98)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.getIndexes(InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.java:759)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.TableInformationImpl.indexes(TableInformationImpl.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.TableInformationImpl.getIndex(TableInformationImpl.java:138)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applyUniqueKeys(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:370)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.performTablesMigration(GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.java:85)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.performMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:207)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:114)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:183)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:310)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:467)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:939)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column i.indproc does not exist
  Подсказка: Perhaps you meant to reference the column "i.indpred".
  Позиция: 610
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2103)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1836)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:257)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:512)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:374)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeQuery(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:254)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2DatabaseMetaData.getIndexInfo(AbstractJdbc2DatabaseMetaData.java:4127)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.getIndexes(InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.java:719)
    ... 31 more
```

Структура базы :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что это за служебные колонки i.indproc,i.indpred и в чём может заключаться проблема?

Comment: Колонки [pg_index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/catalog-pg-index.html). Проблема может заключаться в несовместимости версии jdbc-драйвера и СУБД.

Answer (score 1):

Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column i.indproc does not exist

Либо колонка действительно отсутствует из-за чего и летит ексепшн, либо, как и сказали выше - несовместимость версий

Comment: версия сервера 10.6, jdbc (4.2) - 42.2.5.  Должно работать